# delete from MySQL database using checkboxes

Tags: php, checkbox, mysqli

I'm attempting to delete a row from a table with data that is generated from a MySQL table. I took a look at both of these questions: 
   1. How to delete rows of database results using checkbox 
   2.Deleting multiple rows using checkboxes, PHP and MySQL.

I need help for code delete using checkboxes..

```
<?php

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM leads ORDER BY lid ASC");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 0){
   echo '<tr><td colspan="8">No Data Entry</td></tr>';
}else{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        echo '<tr>
                <td> <input name"checkbox[]" value"'.$row['lid'].'" type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['sex'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['phone'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['company'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['vehicle'].'</td>
            </tr>';
        }
    }?>
```

Cancel

```
 <?php

   $del_lid = $_POST['checkbox']; 
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
     foreach($del_lid as $value){
       $sql = "DELETE FROM leads WHERE lid='".$value."'";
       $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Any kind of help or suggestions are appreciated. thank you....

Comment: missing an equals sign from `value"'.$row['lid'].'"`

Comment: where your facing problem ?

Comment: thank you for response guys the true is i newbie in php coding @JYoThl i thing my problem for execute the delete statement.

Answer (score 2):

The checkboxes were missing the equals sign so effectively none of them had a value. The sql could be streamlined to use the `in` operator rather than a loop.

```
    <table>
<?php

    $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM leads ORDER BY lid ASC");
    if( mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 0 ){
        echo '<tr><td colspan="8">No Data Entry</td></tr>';
    }else{
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){
            echo '
            <tr>
                <td> <input name="checkbox[]" value="'.$row['lid'].'" type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['sex'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['phone'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['company'].'</td>
                <td>'.$row['vehicle'].'</td>
            </tr>';
        }
    }
?>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" value="delete">
        <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Cancel</a></td>
    </form>
</div>
<?php

    $del_lid = $_POST['checkbox']; 

    if ( isset($_POST['submit'] ) ) {
        $sql='delete from `leads` where `lid` in ( ' . implode( ',', $del_lid ). ' )';
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
?>
```

Comment: How about using SQL injection protection: `$del_lid = array_map('intval',$_POST['checkbox']);`

Comment: True - SQL Injection is an issue - a prepared statement would be much better but the `array_map` function call is a good shout!

Comment: Hello Ram i still getting an error Notice: Undefined index: checkbox in C:\xampp\htdocs\mysqlicrud\leads.php on line 49 this line => $del_lid = $_POST['checkbox'];

Comment: <input name"checkbox[]" is missing the equals sign after `name`

Comment: :) didn't spot that one ~ clearly not enough coffee yet

Comment: LOL Ram hahahha

Comment: @ram no error found but my delete execute still not working :(

Comment: check whether the delete throws an error using `if(!$result) echo mysqli_error($conn);`

Comment: thank you very much guys i got the answers  i missed the if ( isset($_POST['submit'] ) ) suppose to be if ( isset($_POST['delete'] ) )  sorry my bad but thank you again for help

Comment: <script language="javascript">
function validate()
{
var chks = document.getElementsByName('checkbox[]');
var hasChecked = false;
for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++)
{
if (chks[i].checked)
{
hasChecked = true;
break;
}
}
if (hasChecked == false)
{
alert("Please select at least one.");
return false;
}
return true;
}
</script>

Comment: that my JavaScript functions but i still getting an error